# Jmeter - current active threads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to get the value of number of threads that are active in an iteration

Is there any function or command that returns that number of active threads in an iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), something like:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads(),)}
```

will return the number of currently active threads (virtual users)

In the above snippet `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function